# Common basis of Hamiltonian and another operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, commutator

I have a Hamiltonian of $N\times N$ matrix, when I diagonalize it , I observe that the $N$ different eigenstates of the hamiltonian are also eigenstates of another operator $\hat O$ where the corresponding eigenvalues are $1$ or $-1$ ,in a strange order, which I try hard to understand but I couldn't , so can anyone give me suggestions on what I should check to understand it.

Comment: We are far more likely to be able to give you a useful answer if you tell us what the operator $\hat{O}$ is.

Comment: the problem is too long to describe here , furthermore I thought that there is a  mathematical reason behind that , that's why I didn't go into details , you can think about this operator like a parity operator .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a non degenerate Hamiltonian (I am guessing this from your question) $H$ that commutes with $O$.

The order of the eigenvalues are arbitrary in the sense that by choosing a different unitary transformation (ie diagonalizing in a slightly different way) you can get a different order of $+1$ and $-1$s.

Since H is non degenerate and O commutes with H, every eigenvector of H is an eigenvector of O. (It something easy to prove $H\psi=E\psi$, non-degeneracy and $[H,O]=0$ together imply $O\psi = o\psi$.)

Let $H = UDU^\dagger$ be diagonalization of $H$, ie $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal. $U$ as a matrix contains orthonormal eigenvectors of H in its columns. $D$ contains the corresponding eigenvalues in the same order.

Consider a rearrangement of columns of $U$ to get say $V$. Correspondingly rearrange rows of $U^\dagger$ to get $V^\dagger$, and rearrange diagonal elements of $D$ to get $D'$. The new $U$ is still unitary. Check that $H$ is still given by $VD'V^\dagger$. This tells you that the ordering of the eigenvectors have nothing great about them. You can rearrange eigenvectors such that those eigenvectors of H that have O-eigenvalue $1$, occur in the first part and the $-1$ in the second part.

A simple way to separate the two sets of eigenstates will be to Diagonalize $\frac{1+O}{2}H\frac{1+O}{2}$ to collect H-eigenstates $\{\psi_{i,+1}\}_i$ with O-eigenvalue +1 and then diagonalize  $\frac{1-O}{2}H\frac{1-O}{2}$ to collect H-eigenstates $\{\psi_{i,-1}\}_i$ with O-eigenvalue -1.

Comment: so you are saying that understanding this order will add nothing since it would be different for different arrangement .but I think it will help me understand the properties of the system ,  since the  order of the eigenvectors  in my system do have physical  meaning( ground state ,  first excited state ..) , so I can't describe the system depending upon this order,? , think about operator O like a parity operator and I know nothing about the wave function of the system since the Hamiltonian can't be solved analytically , so this order would tell about the parity of each eigenvector ??